# JSON object returning empty string for key that has a value

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, dictionary

I have never done any kind of web programming but I need to request a JSON object and save the data in objective-c form. I am using the documentation at `http://eandata.com/blog/e53/data-feed-v3---access-and-data-layout/` but I am unable to retrieve any of the strings associated with a matching key. An example JSON object I am trying to parse is `http://eandata.com/feed/?v=3&keycode=027F74ED52886617&mode=json&find=883929215010&get=all` The top level JSON object returns three keys; status, product, and company. So I access the product key and assign it to  an NSDictionary. In that dictionary is another NSDictionary with the key attributes, so I pull out that dictionary and assign it. Inside the attributes dictionary is a key product with the value of a string. This is the string I need to get, but for some reason it is printing as the empty string. Here is the relevant code.

Scanning the barcode and initiation of GET request

```
#pragma  ZBarDelegate
- (void) imagePickerController: (UIImagePickerController*) reader
 didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo: (NSDictionary*) info
{
    // ADD: get the decode results
    id<NSFastEnumeration> results =
    [info objectForKey: ZBarReaderControllerResults];
    ZBarSymbol *symbol = nil;
    for(symbol in results)
        break;

    NSString *scannedNumber = symbol.data;//@"0049000006582";
    NSString *name = symbol.typeName;
    NSLog(@"The type name is %@", name);

    NSString *eanDataExample =
    @"http://eandata.com/feed/?v=3&keycode=027F74ED52886617&mode=json&find=";
    [ eanDataExample stringByAppendingString:scannedNumber ];
    eanDataExample =
    [ eanDataExample stringByAppendingString:@"&get=all" ];

    NSURL *url = [ NSURL URLWithString:eanDataExample ];
    NSURLRequest *request =
    [ NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url ];
    connection = [ NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self ];
    if ( connection ) {
        webData = [ [ NSMutableData alloc ] init];
    }
    /*resultImage.image =
    [info objectForKey: UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];*/

    // ADD: dismiss the controller (NB dismiss from the *reader*!)
    [reader dismissModalViewControllerAnimated: YES];
}
```

Here are the URLConnection delegate methods

```
#pragma NSURLConnectionDataDelegate Methods
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection
didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
    [webData setLength:0 ];

}
- (void) connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
    [ webData appendData:data ];
}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
}

-(void) connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
    NSDictionary *allDataDictionary =
    [ NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:webData options:0 error:nil ];
    NSArray *keys = [ allDataDictionary allKeys ];
    NSLog(@"The count of all keys is %d", keys.count);
    NSDictionary *product = [ allDataDictionary objectForKey:@"product"];
    NSDictionary *attributes = [ product objectForKey:@"attributes"];
    NSLog(@"The number of attributes are %d", attributes.count);
    NSArray *attKeys = [ attributes allKeys ];
    NSString *desc;
    for (NSString *s in attKeys) {
        if ( [ [ attributes objectForKey:s ] isKindOfClass:[NSString class ] ] ) {
            NSLog(@"The %@ object is a NSSTring", s);
        }
        NSLog(@"The att key is %@", s );
        if ( [ s isEqualToString:@"product"] ) {
            desc =
            [ attributes objectForKey:@"product" ];
            NSLog(@"The description is %@", desc);
        }
    }

}
```

Relevant log statements. I have only included those related to the field I am trying to access.

```
2013-11-17 11:25:21.254 Collections[860:60b] The product object is a NSSTring
2013-11-17 11:25:21.255 Collections[860:60b] The att key is product
2013-11-17 11:25:21.256 Collections[860:60b] The description is
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I tried your code, plugging in the complete url that you posted in your question, it worked fine. You should log your `url` variable to see what you're actually passing to your request. It looks like you never actually append the scanned number, because of this line:

```
[ eanDataExample stringByAppendingString:scannedNumber ];
```

You don't assign the value of that expression is to anything. It should be:

```
eanDataExample = [eanDataExample stringByAppendingString:scannedNumber];
```

Comment: Never done this kind of thing before so I figured I was doing something wrong in understanding access to the data. Turns out the all parameter passed in the URL will return these keys even if the fields are blanks.